# autocompleteextender not working on vb.net

Tags: vb.net, autocompleteextender

i have use ajax autocompleteextender on vb.net it is fine work on c# but not working in vb.net so if any solution then sujjest me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must be probably doing a simple error when converting the code from C# to VB .NET
If it works perfectly on C#, i don't see a reason for it to not work in VB .NET if the code is perfectly converted from C#